# Multi-OS/Arch NPM plugin for Unity

Tags: unity

I need to create a NPM package containing a package for Unity.  I need to use native code, i. e. a native library.  The package needs to support:

- Windows x86 64bit
- Linux x86 64bit
- Embedded Linux ARM

I have written the code for the three native libraries and the C# glue code.  Each library is in its own subdirectory inside of the package folder structure and Unity has generated a meta file each time. I. e., I have

```
    <package root>/
    ├── package.json
    ├── README.md
    ├── (other files)
    └── assets/
        ├── Runtime.meta
        └── Runtime/
            └── Plugins/
                ├── arm.meta
                ├── arm/
                │   ├── libConnect.so
                │   └── libConnect.so.meta
                ├── linux.meta
                ├── linux/
                │   ├── libConnect.so
                │   └── libConnect.so.meta
                ├── windows.meta
                └── windows/
                    ├── Connect.DLL
                    └── Connect.DLL.meta
```

Depending on the platform I build for, I'd like Unity to use the appropriate native library.

However, I can't seem to set the properties on the native libs to the right values using the [Unity Inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/PlugInsCombined.png) on the libraries. In particular, I cannot seem to set the Embedded Linux ARM lib to ARM CPU without the Linux lib also changing to ARM CPU. Vice versa, changint the Linux lib to "Intel 64-bit" CPU also sets the Embedded Linux ARM lib to that CPU. Also, the windows DLL always seems to end up in Embedded Linux builds, no matter what settings I use. I tried in- and excluding different platforms for different libs, but still, changes to one lib seem to magically mess up changes I made to the other libs.

Please tell me how I can achive my goal, to have three native libs for different platforms and have Unity use the right one depending on which platform I build for.

Comment: Linux on ARM is still Linux.  Try reorganizing the structure to place ARM under Linux(ARM and X64 should be separate directories).  "Also, the windows DLL always seems to end up in Embedded Linux builds"  The dll file is platform independent  with .net 6+.